# Adding additional libraries to solr's war file

Tags: solr, war, solr4

To simplify process of deploying my applications i want to add some libraries to war file.
I expect to have all-in-one war file which i deploy under tomcat, and separated solr core directory in another location. Currently im using war file from dist directory and separated directory with these libraries linked in solrconfig.xml, but due to differences between production and development enviroment it's not possible to mantain such configuration without pain. 
I want to distribute single war-file with all libraries compilled.
It is possible, if yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your libs into `WEB-INF/libs` folder in `.war` archive.